# React app working in windows but not on Ubuntu

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app which is working perfectly fine on windows but it is not working on my live ubuntu server. I get the following console msgs in chrome when I try to visit the page.

[image]

I am not able to figure out what is the issue here. I re-run npm install and checked code. Code is running fine on windowns but not on ubuntu server.

I get the following error in ubuntu command prompt:
[image]

Comment: you are not clarifying the deployment process you made at all. follow [this React deployment guide](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/).

Comment: I think I am familiar with this issue. Can you try this out? Remove the react-dev-tools from the production code base and check your app working fine in ubuntu. If this works can you tell me? Then I can post this as the answer?

Comment: will try. I updated the question. posted the terminal error msgs. can you have a look at it?

Comment: problem solved. file name had a Capital letter but script didn't have..

Answer (score 0):

It was the problem with the file "bin - Copy.png"

script was looking for "bin - copy.png" whereas the file name was "bin - Copy.png"

I edited the file name and everything worked well.